# $apply already in progress With Custom Directive and Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a custom directive around a third-party jQuery plugin. The third-party jQuery plugin handles updates to its data using events, so my directive watches for the events and uses $apply to make sure it properly updates the data that's getting passed in from a controller. I also want to be able to update the data in the plugin so I have a method for modifying/updating the data via my own method call on the scope of my directive. However, when an angular directive triggers the method call on my directive (in this case, via an ng-click), it causes the '$apply already in progress' Angular error. I think this is happening because Angular's built-in directives already call $apply or $digest for me or something to that effect. I've found a way to get around this problem using $timeout, but it feels like one of those "ick, don't do that" sorts of things. Everything works fine when the third party plugin fires events of its own via normal interactions with the plugin (i.e. I don't get the $apply in progress error and the data is updated on the scope the way I would expect).

Can anyone help me figure out a better way to do what I'm trying to do? I've included sample code and a fiddle here that illustrates the problem (this isn't the real directive, it's much simpler and I don't have control over the third party jQuery plugin and the events it throws etc.).

<del>[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/davertron/jEfc4/)</del>

[Better jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/davertron/jEfc4/3/)

**UPDATE**
New code to better illustrate the problem:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="blarf">
<div ng-controller="blah">
    <p>Controller view of numbers:</p>
    <ul><li ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{number}}</li></ul>
    <p>Directive view</p>
    <some-awesome-directive numbers="numbers"></some-awesome-directive>
</div>
<button id="sneaky-adder" type="button">Add (Sneaky) Number</button>
```

JavaScript

```
(function(){ 
    var data = [1, 2, 3];

    window.getData = function(){ return data; }
    window.addNumber = function(number){ 
        data.push(number); 
        $('.adder-directive').trigger('my-custom-event', [number]);
    };

    $(document).on('click', '#sneaky-adder', function(){
        var newNum = (Math.random() * 20) + ' sneaky :)';
        data.push(newNum);
        $('.adder-directive').trigger('my-custom-event', [newNum]);
    });
})();

angular.module('blarf', [])
.controller('blah', function($scope){
    $scope.numbers = getData();
})
.directive('someAwesomeDirective', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            numbers: '=',
        },
        template: '<div class="adder-directive"><ul><li ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{number}}</li></ul><button type="button" id="adder" ng-click="addAnotherNumber()">Add Another Number</button></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.addAnotherNumber = function(){
                // 1.
                /*$timeout(function(){
                    var newNum = Math.random() * 20;
                    addNumber(newNum);
                });*/

                // 2.
                var newNum = Math.random() * 20;
                addNumber(newNum);
            };

            $(element).on('my-custom-event', function(e, number){
                // 3.
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.numbers = getData();
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**OLD STUFF**

HTML

```
<div ng-app="blarf">
    <div ng-controller="blah">
        <some-awesome-directive numbers="numbers"></some-awesome-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
angular.module('blarf', [])
.controller('blah', function($scope){
    $scope.numbers = [1,2,3];
})
.directive('someAwesomeDirective', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            numbers: '=',
        },
        template: '<div><ul><li ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{number}}</li></ul><button type="button" ng-click="addAnotherNumber()">Add Another Number</button></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element){
            scope.addAnotherNumber = function(){
                // 1. This works, uncomment this and comment out 2 to see
                //$timeout(function(){ element.triggerHandler('my-custom-event', [Math.random() * 20])});

                // 2. This causes an "$apply already in progress" error 
                element.triggerHandler('my-custom-event', [Math.random() * 20])
            };

            element.on('my-custom-event', function(e, number){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.numbers.push(number);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Do I understand you correct, without scope.$apply, the scope property is not updated?

Comment: @Narretz UPDATE: Actually in the case of the fiddle I posted if you remove the $scope.$apply the data still updates correctly because the ng-click correctly schedules a $digest or whatever, but in the actual custom directive I'm writing there are other ways for the data to get mutated that angular isn't aware of. I'll see if I can update the fiddle in a way that demonstrates removing the $scope.$apply breaks the bindings.

Comment: Wrapping `$apply` in `$timeout` is perfectly fine and preferred over accessing `$$phase`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the call to $apply in a function like this:

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
        }
    } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
    }
};
```

Comment: I've seen this solution here and there when trying to find an answer to my problem and was apprehensive to use it because I saw comments that said "do not do that". Is this a hacky workaround or a valid, Angular-sanctioned way to handle this problem?

Comment: Well, you should strive to a) not use scope.$apply in the first place, and b) not resort to safeApply unless absolutely necessary. But interacting with things like jQuery plugins that operate outside of Angular's digest cycle often leaves you with having to do things like this, or re-write the entire plugin to be more Angular compatible.

Comment: The whole concept of $scope.$apply is basically a workaround for something like Object.observe. In fact, 'safe apply' is used inside angular core at least once. There are certainly cases where it is necessary to use such strategies, although I find this one a little overblown. A simple ``` if ($scope.$$phase) { ... }``` has alwaays worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could put your logic into a function that is called both by the button (from angular) and from the event (to only be called outside angular):

```
scope.handleNumber(number) {
    scope.numbers.push(number);
};

scope.addAnotherNumber = function() {
    scope.handleNumber(Math.random() * 20);
};

element.on('my-custom-event', function(e, number) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.handleNumber(number);
    });
};
```

Comment: The initial code/fiddle I posted above don't accurately show the problem. I can't actually separate out the function like you show in this case because it's the library that's firing the event and adding the values to itself etc., but good suggestion!